# Python regex and accented Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I have problem with my Python RegEx treatment bloc when it deals with accented Expression. 
When I run my code:

```
import re
title = ur"Titre : c'est pas gréable à Infos:"
print title
m = re.findall(":(.+?) Infos",title , re.UNICODE)
print unicode((m))
```

i have this result:

```
Titre : c'est pas gréable à Infos:
[u" c'est pas gr\xe9able \xe0"]
```

I need to be able to keep accented expression in the result output. 
Thanks for helping

Comment: You are just seeing two different representations of the same unicode string, one with the unicode characters and one with their utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
  print unicode((m), 'utf-8').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The same problem persist